# Another Moderator Pro Tempore fresh from the fryer

Tags: discussion, moderators

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that another member has stepped up and generously volunteered his time to help us assure that this community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: OddThinking]

OddThinking joins [our existing moderators](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230/moderator-pro-tem-announcement) in serving this community. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute. Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: You may all now bow before me... err, I mean, this is a great honour, and  I look forward to serving the community however I can.

Comment: Great news! Welcome to the other side... We have cookies :)

Comment: Welcome to hell, @Oddthinking! Population: 4

Comment: Ugh. I hate that guy. j/k … good decision!

Comment: @Sklivvz: I need to have a chat to you about those cookies you promised me.

Comment: @Oddthinking: cookies are reserved for pro-tems. Maybe you want a hat? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Oddthinking is now moderator for a while, time to get this post off the unanswered list.