# Wash away the nutrients - is not a notable claim!

Tags: discussion, notability

Why the question "[Is drinking water during a meal bad for you?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1870/is-drinking-water-during-a-meal-bad-for-you)" wasn't closed as it doesn't offer any notable claim?

Can someone explain why this question was so up-voted if it doesn't offer any reference to that the drinking water washes away the nutrients in your stomach?

It is a type of question "I have heard".

Answer (score 2):

As commented: our rules were refined as we progressed. In particular you will find many questions from 2011 which are a bit different from today's expectations.

Also: explicit proof notability for commonly heard claims is not really needed. If a lot of people heard a claim it is considered notable (I would still advise to present a specific instance of a claim to prevent inaccurate claims).

Comment: This [answer to another question](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3183/have-quality-standards-for-answers-been-increasing-over-time/3191#3191) fleshes out the timeline of the developing standards a little.