# Why does the "moderators" link deny that user=Sklivvz is a moderator?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, moderators

When I click on the "moderators" link:

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators

exactly four moderators are listed: Jamiec, Larian LeQuella, Mad Scientist, and Oddthinking

But another link

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/96/sklivvz

indicates that Sklivvz is a moderator too.

Are there any other users whose profiles indicate they are moderators, but are left off the "moderators" link list?

Are all the alleged moderators (including Sklivvz) equally and really moderators?

Why is Sklivvz left off the list?

Comment: It's a conspiracy man! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because I was elected as a moderator, but then hired by Stack Exchange as a developer. Developers, employees and community managers do not normally appear in that list even if they have mod powers.

Generally speaking, I act as a mod only on skeptics since I moderated the site since the beginning and I know how the community works. I don't really moderate anywhere else, although I do have mod powers everywhere.

I do not use any developer-level powers as a moderation tool.

Other employees have moderated the site in the past (in a limited fashion): codinghorror, spolsky, rcartaino, shog9...

Comment: But, you are still an elected mod, representing this community? Like, you didn't step down from your elected role when you took your SE job, right?

Comment: I never officially retired as a mod, it's just how the software works. When I started being a developer we ran another election to bring more hands on board. See the announcement [here](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/2175/96). There is no sensible way in which I can be an active user and not a moderator, since our sites are made to be moderated by the users...

Comment: When I say moderator, translate to "moderator indicated by a diamond with extra privileges normally bestowed by election" then. You're still one of those, right?

Comment: And [this page](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) distinguishes between moderators and users. "*Moderators also have some special abilities*", "*Moderators can place users in timed suspension, and delete users if necessary*", etc. So, based on the way StackExchange uses the word "moderator", it's totally possible to be an active user and not a moderator in the sense of the word that that page uses it.

Comment: @Dawn: That's kind of true, but consider "Vote to Close", which normally takes 5 high-rep users to complete. Mods and devs *only* get super-votes, that instantly close. There is no way to do a normal user vote. That said, Sklivvz has used mod/employee powers when, for example, dealing with users who have been abusive to others.

Comment: @Dawn To be clear, 99% of *any* mod work is answering flags and voting, which in large part is high-rep-mod work. However as Oddthinking pointed out, our votes are heavy and we can't waive that privilege -- the reason being more trusted via election.

Comment: @Sklivvz So I don't get it... are you still an elected moderator (moderator in the sense described at [this page](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) with special privileges of suspension, deletion, full profile info, etc) representing *this* community? I thought you were.

Comment: I am an elected moderator *and* an employee. Employees do not appear in that list.

Comment: @Dawn: I believe employees automatically get all of the extra privileges associated with specific site moderators. Does that resolve the confusion?

Comment: @sumelic My confusion was whether Sklivvz is still representing *this* community, or whether Sklivvz is representing StackExchange, or somehow both. If both, it would be good to know how he balances the two.

Comment: @Dawn can you be more specific? What concerns you exactly?

Comment: @Sklivvz I don't have any concerns. I just don't know whether you are still representing this community, or whether you are representing StackExchange, or somehow both.

Comment: @dawn what do you mean by "represent"? I'm a dev and a mod: they are very separate activities. In other words: when I *develop* the site I work as a dev; when I *use* the site, I am a mod.

Comment: @Sklivvz Say a person is an employee, never elected by a community, but gets a diamond beside their name. My understanding would be that their moderation actions wouldn't be on behalf of a particular community's will, but rather that of StackExchange's. However, for diamond mods that are elected by a community and are not employees, their actions would be on behalf of that community that elected them, and they'd be responsible to that community. Is that understanding correct? If so, it is that sense of "represent" that I'm talking about.

Comment: @Sklivvz So, you are still modding on *this site's behalf* rather than as an employee when you use your diamond mod privileges here?

Comment: @Sklivvz Have you ever used dev access to get information that a non-employee diamond mod would not have, to look into links between accounts... to see if a new account is related to an old account, for example?

Comment: @Dawn ah, I understand now. So: employees do not moderate, except community team and some devs. Even then, we are all very conscious of what you are saying about representing the community. I believe that mods (all together!) represent the community -- many of my "mod" actions are taken with the full knowledge/agreement of the other mods.

Comment: @Dawn re "related accounts". While I have deeper data as a dev, usually normal mod tools catch all sockpuppets. As devs we are asked, at times, to investigate further some special cases, but that's never happened to me. In any case I would always involve a different dev if it happened here (more eyes = better outcome).

Comment: @Sklivvz Thanks, that's clear now :)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of years after this question was posted, the list changed again.

- Sklivvz is back on the list, but is marked as being "appointed 2/17/2017" (although he was one of the original [mods pro tem](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/230/37236) and was reelected via a formal election [in 2012](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2560/37236)). February 2nd, 2017 is the same day that it was announced on [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291152/323179) that he would no longer be an employee.
- Larian LeQuella doesn't appear to be a moderator anymore. He's not in the list and doesn't have a diamond.

Comment: Larian is on hiatus

Comment: @Sklivvz Thanks for the info. Is this going to be announced in its own meta post? I was kinda frustrated I had to stumble upon this info instead of it being announced.

Comment: I don't know, I don't think these things are usually announced. Also, I know very little beyond that "he was a little busy".